What is Canonical Problem in Artificial and Natural Development
I am reading the book, “Foundations of Computational Intelligence Volume 1 Learning and Approximation” and there is a definition that I cannot understand.

Artificial Development is a field of Evolutionary Computation inspired
by the developmental processes and cellular growth seen in nature.
Multiple models of artificial development have been proposed in the
past, which can be broadly divided into those based on biochemical
processes and those based on a high-level grammar. Chapter 8,
“Artificial Development”, by Chavoya covers the main research areas
pertaining to artificial development with an emphasis toward the
systems based on artificial regulatory networks. To this end, a short
introductionto biological gene regulatory networks and their
relationship with development is first presented. The sections on the
various artificial development models are followed by a section on the
canonical problem in artificial and natural development known as the
French flag problem.

What is “canonical problem in artificial and natural development” in this context? Thanks in advance.

As hinted by your reference the French flag problem is one of the canonical problems in artificial and natural development based on morphogen in early biological development.

The French flag model is a conceptual definition of a morphogen... During early development, morphogen gradients generate different cell types in distinct spatial order. French flag patterning is often found in combination with others: vertebrate limb development is one of the many phenotypes exhibiting French flag patterning overlapped with a complementary pattern (in this case Turing pattern).

In summary the French flag pattern and Turing patterns work together to ensure precise and robust limb and other generic phenotype formations. The French flag pattern sets up broad zones where different types of structures will form. Within these zones, Turing patterns refine the structure by creating regularly spaced and well-defined segments. These are canonical problems in artificial and natural development.
